# how to get the child number in js or php

Tags: javascript, php, html

How to get the child number ?

[check screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcnfd.png)

so when i click on the X button, that element will be removed, but it's only for item n2, so i need to get the number of the child when i click on it

```html
<div class="col-xs-4">
       <a class="postimgsd" onclick="if(confirm('Are you sure, want to delete this image?')){delImage(2572);}else{} ">
        <span class="close">X</span> <img src="site/32000/2572/51c1e0a5f8715e33e74e58798cdc0f4d.jpg"></a></div>
```

i tired

```
    var child = document.getElementsByClassName('col-xs-4');
    var parent = child.parentNode;
    var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(parent.children, child);
```

but i got

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined
>       at :3:53

How can i do that ?

Comment: How is this duplicated ? maybe there's someone asked the same question but it's not the one mentioned

Comment: i asked about how to got that number not how to fix that problem, i mean different code maybe

Comment: In my opinion they close questions way too easily. Anyway. I updated my answer, let me know if it worked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array, so when you use `parentNode`, you get `undefined` and you're trying to get the property `children` of an undefined variable.

What you can do is give each image a unique ID like `id="image_123"` and store this ID in the corresponding close button with a `data-{name}` attribute like `data-gallery-image-id="image_123"`. When the button's `click` event is triggered, use the `event.target.getAttribute('data-gallery-image-id')` to get the ID of the image. Now you can use `document.getElementById()` to get the image you'd like to remove.

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped, appreciate your help !

Comment: @JDEV Great to hear!